# Trying to autofill form but its not working using GeckoFX

Tags: c#, geckofx

I'm trying to autofill a form but it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   GeckoHtmlElement Username;
   Username = Browser.Document.GetHtmlElementById("usernameLogin");
   Username.SetAttribute("Value", textBox1.Text);
}
```

So where is the problem?

Edit: Maybe my problem is that there are more than one `usernameLogin` elements. How can I select the one I want?

Page source:

```
<input class="js_userName" type="text" tabindex="1" onkeydown="hideLoginErrorBox();" id="usernameLogin" name="login" value="">
```

Comment: Being explicit about what exactly isn't working is helpful when asking a question. (eg. it throws exception or the value doesn't appear in the field.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Geckofx 45

try casting the return type to a GeckoInputElement.

```
var username = (GeckoInputElement)Browser.Document.GetHtmlElementById("usernameLogin");
```

Then you can use the Value property.

```
username.Value = textBox1.Text;
```